# How to find the overall top played game name by each player along with number of times played SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL query to find the overall top played game name by each player along with number of times played?

Tables info -

- Table - A has the information of number of times a player has played each game in any day.
- Table - B has the game id to game name mapping

```
Table A :

| Player_id | Date | Game_id | number of times played |

| --------- | ---- | ------- | ---------------------- |


1   03-09-2020  2   365
1   03-09-2020  3   712
1   04-09-2020  1   346
1   06-09-2020  3   516
1   07-09-2020  1   143
1   07-09-2020  2   882
1   07-09-2020  3   933
2   01-09-2020  1   181
2   01-09-2020  2   1000
2   01-09-2020  3   658
2   02-09-2020  1   723
2   02-09-2020  2   461
2   02-09-2020  3   173
2   07-09-2020  1   953
2   07-09-2020  2   562
2   07-09-2020  3   329
3   01-09-2020  1   644
3   01-09-2020  2   709
3   01-09-2020  3   553
3   02-09-2020  1   659
3   05-09-2020  1   130
3   05-09-2020  2   203
3   05-09-2020  3   437
3   06-09-2020  1   964
3   07-09-2020  2   772
3   07-09-2020  3   241
4   01-09-2020  1   882
4   01-09-2020  2   658
4   05-09-2020  1   673
4   05-09-2020  2   326
4   05-09-2020  3   482
4   07-09-2020  2   843
4   07-09-2020  3   348
5   01-09-2020  1   567
5   01-09-2020  2   484
5   01-09-2020  3   670
```

```
Table B :

Game_ID | Game_Name
1         Poker
2         Rummy
3         Carrom
```

```
Desired Result:

Player id | Game Name | number_of_times_played  
1           Carrom      4030    
2           Poker       5083
```

Comment: What happened to players 3 and 4 and 5?

Comment: Haven't mentioned here because of code vs text limitation here but they should be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be aggregation to get the totals for each player and name -- and window functions to get the top one.  Then a `join`:

```
select pg.player_id, pg.game_id, g.game_name, pg.num_times
from (select player_id, game_id, sum(num_times) as num_times,
             row_number() over (partition by player_id order by sum(num_times) desc) as seqnum
      from a
      group by player_id, game_id
     ) pg join
     b
     on pg.game_id = b.game_id
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: can we join first and then use aggregation and window function?

Comment: @martian_rover . . . Yes.  It would work either way.

Answer (score 1):

We can use sub-query as well:

```
Select t1.Player_id,b,Game_name,t1.num_play as number of times_played from 
    (Select Player_id,Game_id,sum(number_of_times_played) as num_play, row_number() over (partition by player_id order by sum(number_of_times_played) desc) as row_num from table_A group by Player_id,Game_id) as t1 join table_B b on (t1.Game_id=b.Game_id) where row_num=1;
```